# sudo ./get_folder.sh no such file or directory

Tags: scripts, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm following an instruction guide in order to install programs on ubuntu 20.04 LTS WSL.
However, the error occurs when asked to write the line "sudo ./get_folder.sh"

```
/usr/local/bin/test$ sudo ./get_folder.sh
grep: ./get_folder.sh: No such file or directory
./get_folder.sh: line 13: /usr/local/bin/linux_bin/get_folder.sh.runme: Success
```

Im in the directory "/usr/local/bin/test$" which contains the script get_folder.sh

What should happen, according to the guide, is that the files from downloaded folder get placed in /usr/local/bin/.

why cant I run the script?

Additional info that could help:
my bashrc is

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export KMP_STACKSIZE=8m
export DISPLAY=:0
```

The webpage from the script is from contains this text:

"As root, the script copies the programs into /usr/local/bin/linux_bin, and links them to /usr/local/bin. As a normal user, they are downloaded to $HOME/bin/linux_bin, and linked to your $HOME/bin. In the latter case, make sure that $HOME/bin is in your $PATH."

Comment: It looks like the script itself runs but the commands inside it are flawed.

Comment: Agreed.  Your title is actually a bit misleading.  The real error is "**grep:** ./get_folder.sh: No such file or directory" (emphasis added).  Since *you* didn't run the `grep` command, something in the script is causing that.

Answer (score 1):

Given the instructions you quoted in your question, I assume you are trying to install XDS from [this page](https://strucbio.biologie.uni-konstanz.de/xdswiki/index.php?title=Installation&mobileaction=toggle_view_mobile).

**Note:**  While I can solve your installation problem, it looks to me like XDS requires a full-blown graphical environment, something that WSL does not *currently* provide.  See the end of this answer for more details on that.

As far as I can tell, the installation script is simply bugged.  It starts with this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$(whoami)" == "root" ]; then
  export DESTINATION=/usr/local/bin/linux_bin
else
  export DESTINATION=$HOME/bin/linux_bin
fi
mkdir -p $DESTINATION
cd $DESTINATION
# run a "runme" helper script so that the current get_folder.sh may be overwritten by the new one:
grep -v runme ./get_folder.sh > ./get_folder.sh.runme
chmod +x ./get_folder.sh.runme
exec ./get_folder.sh.runme && exit

wget -O- https://strucbio.biologie.uni-konstanz.de/pub/linux_bin/xds_extra_linux.tar | tar xjvf -
```

When run with `sudo`, that:

- Creates the `/usr/local/bin/linux_bin` directory
- Changes to that directory
- Attempts to create and run a copy of itself (the script) so that the original can be overwritten by newly downloaded files in the last line.  The `grep` command removes the "self-replicating" portion of the script from the newly created copy.

However, because of the `cd`, the script *just isn't there*.  It's attempting to run the grep against `/usr/local/bin/linux_bin/get_folder.sh`, but the script is still in the original location.

The result is an *empty* `/usr/local/bin/linux_bin/get_folder.sh.runme`, which *does* get executed "successfully" in line 13, as you can see from the message.  But, of course, running an empty script doesn't do anything.

That's it - The "copy-of-the-script" then exits, without even getting to the "download and untar" step.

Likely the creators of the script have fallen into a bit of a mental "trap" - When they are testing it, they are likely always running it on a system where they already have it installed.  So it works.  But it *won't* work the first time.

The solution is fairly simple.  While you mention that you are running this on Windows Subsystem for Linux, the failure actually occurs on plain-Jane Ubuntu as well.  BUT, the nice thing about WSL is that I can spin up a new "throwaway" instance in less than a minute in order to test something like this without bloating my everyday session with software I don't need.  So I actually did test this out, and it worked:

From the directory with your `get_folder.sh`:

```
sudo mv get_folder.sh /usr/local/bin/linux_bin
cd /usr/local/bin/linux_bin
sudo ./get_folder.sh
```

This works because your previous failed attempts at running the script already created the directory, so you just need to move the script there (where it erronously *expects* to be) and then run it again.

#### Additional information on running graphical applications under WSL

To run graphical apps in WSL, you'll need to do one of two things:

- Enroll in the Windows Insider program and run the latest Preview version of Windows.  This includes support for WSLg, a new feature that will allow you to run a full-blown Linux GUI under WSL.  Of course, you must be willing to deal with any bugs that come along with running a "beta" version of Windows.
- Second option is to manually set up an X Server and the necessary libraries.  This is far beyond the scope of this answer, so I'll just ask you to use your search-engine-of-choice to find *installing x on wsl*.

Please note that I have not done either of these.  I'm very much looking forward to the next Windows release towards the end of this year that includes WSLg in a production version, but I have no need to add support for it before then.